# Get UITableViewCell from another UIViewController's UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in a `HomeViewController`. This `UITableView` has one customized `UITableViewCell` in it. 
I want to use the same `UITableViewCell` in `ListViewController` by dequeueing it. Below code does not work.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeVC: HomeViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController 
if let homeTableView = homeVC.tableView  {
      // Above homeVC.tableView is becoming nil.
      // Would like to dequeue here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot see your `HomeViewController` code, I am assuming the `tableView` property is linked from the Interface Builder as `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`. This means that that `tableView` is not instantiated until the view actually appears on the screen. To prove this, try placing a breakpoint inside your `HomeViewConntroller`s `viewDidLoad()` method, and notice that it is never reached.

To solve your problem, I would add a table view into your `ListViewController`, and copy the custom table cell from `HomeViewController` into your table view. Then create a custom `UITableViewCell`, and in IB assign both cells in `HomeViewController` and `ListViewController` as your custom table view cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a xib file and a custom `UITableViewCell` class for the cell you want to reuse in multiple view controllers. Then, in the xib's identity inspector, define the custom type of the cell as your custom class. Then, register the cell class in each view controller by calling [register](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register) function on the tableView instance in `viewDidLoad`. Then dequeue your cell by implementing UITableViewDataSource's [`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview).